# Removing value of nested Map in another map

Tags: java, lambda, stream

Before I had simple map e.g: `Map<String, Book>`. I needed to add key to this map, so it looks like this `Map<String, Map<String, Book>>`

I need to remove entry on some condition, before I had:

```
map.entrySet()
                .removeIf(matches -> getMinuteDiffrenceBetweenActualAndGivenDate(ChronoUnit.MINUTES, matches.getValue()
                        .getDateOfCreation()) >= 20);
```

Now I need to do the same, I cannot use `get()` as I need to iterate through all values of value in outer map.

I tried to do this way:

```
map.entrySet().removeIf(matches -> matches.getValue().getValue()...
```

but I do not understand why I do not have getValue() method to get Book object.

Comment: This question is not clear. Please check this out and post a minimal and reproducible example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @RavindraRanwala what is not clear? I provided the method that I had previous and what I want to achieve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`matches.getValue()` is a `Map`, not a `Map.Entry`, so it has no `getValue()` method.

You can iterate over the values of the outer `Map` and remove entries of the inner `Map`:

```
map.values()
   .forEach(inner -> inner.entrySet().removeIf(matches -> 
       getMinuteDiffrenceBetweenActualAndGivenDate(ChronoUnit.MINUTES, 
                                                   matches.getValue().getDateOfCreation()) >= 20));
```

EDIT:

To remove entries of the outer Map:

```
map.entrySet()
   .removeIf(entry -> entry.getValue()
                           .values()
                           .stream()
                           .anyMatch(book -> /*some boolean expression*/));
```

Comment: Is there any possibility to remove whole entry? I've written wrongly, because before it was removing whole entry when we removed value and that caused mistake right now.

Comment: @mara122 which entry do you wish to remove? an entry of the outer Map or an entry of the inner Map?

Comment: Outer map, so the result will be completely removing k&v.

Comment: yea, that's what I wanted. Thanks.

Comment: You are awesome! @Eran